# ACF groups inside Option page with Timber

Tags: wordpress, twig, advanced-custom-fields, timber

**This what Im doing:**

1. I have 2 ACF fields inside the option page. `test` and
   `test_my_group`
2. I have 1 group inside my option page name `my_group`
3. The field `test_my_group` located inside `my_group` ACF group.

**My Problem is:**

1. I can easily get the `test` field value inside Timber Tiwg template
   using the tag `{{ options.test }}`
2. I fail to get the `test_my_group` value as its inside the group
   `my_group`
3. If I move the field `test_my_group` out side `my_group`, Now I can
   use `{{ options.test_my_group}}` without any problem.

===
In normal CPT and Posts, I dont have any problem caling the field value if located inside a ACF group by setting the group first then calling the child filled.

```
{% set group = post.meta('group') %}
{{ group.first_field }}
{{ group.second_field }}
```

**My Question IS:**

How to call the group sub-fields of an ACF group inside option page?

Answer (score 1):

I did not found any related documentation describing how to get **ACF options groups sub field values** using Timper. However,

When I look again in the normal group fields Twig function and tags:

```
{% set group = post.meta('group') %}
{{ group.first_field }}
{{ group.second_field }}
```

I noticed the `.` after `group`. And its give a hint with the answer.

The answer to my previous question is:

This tag will fetch the *group sub fields value* from: group array and can be use for multiple sub group level inside options page like:

1. **Options => Group => Sub fields**.
2. **Options => Group => Group => Sub fields**.
3. **etc ....**

**EXAMPLE 1**

If we have the exact same scenario of my question this tag should work to get the ACF options group sub field value:

```
{{ options.GROUP_SLUG.SUB_GROUP_SLUG}}
```

So in my case it was:

```
{{ options.my_group.test_my_group}}
```

**EXAMPLE 2**

1. In the options page we have group with slug `group_1`
2. In this group we have other group with the slug `group_2` **inside** `group_1`
3. In the `group_2` we have sub field name `group_2_field`.

In this case we should use:

```
 {{ options.GROUP_1.GROUP_2.GROUP_2_FIELD}}
```

Which should be in EXAMPLE 2:

```
{{ options.group_1.group_2.group_2_field}}
```

I tested and its working perfect, Also I decided to share this with other so they may use it as hint for something better.